# Set Role to user for login time

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to set Role for some users after login. Note, I don't want to add user to this role permanently and write to db, just set some role after login and then check if this user is in this role. Is it possible ?

Comment: Maybe? You seriously need to give any answerers more details. What membership are you using? What code objects are you using to control users and roles? Do you have example code to show what you mean? What you tried?

Comment: May help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole.aspx

Comment: I know how to use Membership. Roles.AddUserToRole Method adds user to role in DB. I don't need any roles in db and any users in roles. I just need to set role for some users by different conditions and then check role in code. Of course, I can set Session["ReadOnly"] = true, but seems to me role is more careful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create your own AppUser class that has AppRoles.
You can link up your AppRoles to Membership roles (or not).

I do this so I can fake user roles for testing and to contain Membership services code.